# Beautifulsoup missing parts

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to retrieve [saleprice](https://www.redfin.com/TX/Cedar-Park/615-Fence-Post-Pass-78613/home/32939011) from redfin for the house.

Here's the part of HTML:

```
<div class="timeline"><div class="property-history-content-container"><div class="timeline-content"><h4 class="section-header col-12">Today</h4><div class="sold-row row PropertyHistoryEventRow" id="propertyHistory-0"><div class="col-4"><p>Oct 15, 2020</p><p class="subtext">Date</p></div><div class="description-col col-4"><div>Sold (MLS) (Closed)</div><div></div><p class="subtext">ACTRIS #5085856</p></div><div class="col-4"><div class="price-col number">$302,000<span class="number empty"> </span></div><p class="subtext">Price</p></div></div><div class=" row PropertyHistoryEventRow" id="propertyHistory-1"><div class="col-4"><p>Sep 16, 2020</p><p class="subtext">Date</p></div><div class="description-col col-4"><div>Contingent (Active Under Contract)</div><div></div><p class="subtext">ACTRIS #5085856</p></div><div class="col-4"><div class="price-col number">—<span class="number empty"> </span></div><p class="subtext">Price</p></div></div><div class=" row PropertyHistoryEventRow" id="propertyHistory-2"><div class="col-4"><p>Sep 8, 2020</p><p class="subtext">Date</p></div><div class="description-col col-4"><div>Pending (Pending - Taking Backups)</div><div></div><p class="subtext">ACTRIS #5085856</p></div><div class="col-4"><div class="price-col number">—<span class="number empty"> </span></div><p class="subtext">Price</p></div></div><div class=" row PropertyHistoryEventRow" id="propertyHistory-3"><div class="col-4"><p>Sep 5, 2020</p><p class="subtext">Date</p></div><div class="description-col col-4"><div>Listed (Active)</div><div></div><p class="subtext">ACTRIS #5085856</p></div><div class="col-4"><div class="price-col number">$294,900<span class="number empty"> </span></div><p class="subtext">Price</p></div></div></div></div></div>
```

Here's the part of mycode:

```
url = 'https://www.redfin.com/TX/Cedar-Park/615-Fence-Post-Pass-78613/home/32939011'
driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser') 
soup.find_all(class_ = 'timeline-content')
```

However, the code does not return the "sold" event, only 3 events before sold.

Below is the result of `soup.find_all(class_ = 'timeline-content')`

```
[<div class="timeline-content"><h4 class="section-header col-12">Today</h4><div class="row PropertyHistoryEventRow" id="propertyHistory-0"><div class="col-4"><p>Sep 16, 2020</p><p class="subtext">Date</p></div><div class="description-col col-4"><div>Contingent (Active Under Contract)</div><div></div><p class="subtext">ACTRIS #5085856</p></div><div class="col-4"><div class="price-col number">—<span class="number empty"> </span></div><p class="subtext">Price</p></div></div><div class="row PropertyHistoryEventRow" id="propertyHistory-1"><div class="col-4"><p>Sep 8, 2020</p><p class="subtext">Date</p></div><div class="description-col col-4"><div>Pending (Pending - Taking Backups)</div><div></div><p class="subtext">ACTRIS #5085856</p></div><div class="col-4"><div class="price-col number">—<span class="number empty"> </span></div><p class="subtext">Price</p></div></div><div class="row PropertyHistoryEventRow" id="propertyHistory-2"><div class="col-4"><p>Sep 5, 2020</p><p class="subtext">Date</p></div><div class="description-col col-4"><div>Listed (Active)</div><div></div><p class="subtext">ACTRIS #5085856</p></div><div class="col-4"><div class="price-col number empty">**<span class="number empty"> </span></div><p class="subtext">Price</p></div></div></div>]
```

Comment: There is no price there. Unless you are signed in.

Comment: Could you provide the html as text, please.

Comment: Your code do not perform a login, so the the output may differ from the expected one. My Answer is based on your sample html and provide the `price`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the the tag you want to find too `soup.find('div', class_='timeline-content')` that works.

**Example based on provided html**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class="timeline"><div class="property-history-content-container"><div class="timeline-content"><h4 class="section-header col-12">Today</h4><div class="sold-row row PropertyHistoryEventRow" id="propertyHistory-0"><div class="col-4"><p>Oct 15, 2020</p><p class="subtext">Date</p></div><div class="description-col col-4"><div>Sold (MLS) (Closed)</div><div></div><p class="subtext">ACTRIS #5085856</p></div><div class="col-4"><div class="price-col number">$302,000<span class="number empty"> </span></div><p class="subtext">Price</p></div></div><div class=" row PropertyHistoryEventRow" id="propertyHistory-1"><div class="col-4"><p>Sep 16, 2020</p><p class="subtext">Date</p></div><div class="description-col col-4"><div>Contingent (Active Under Contract)</div><div></div><p class="subtext">ACTRIS #5085856</p></div><div class="col-4"><div class="price-col number">—<span class="number empty"> </span></div><p class="subtext">Price</p></div></div><div class=" row PropertyHistoryEventRow" id="propertyHistory-2"><div class="col-4"><p>Sep 8, 2020</p><p class="subtext">Date</p></div><div class="description-col col-4"><div>Pending (Pending - Taking Backups)</div><div></div><p class="subtext">ACTRIS #5085856</p></div><div class="col-4"><div class="price-col number">—<span class="number empty"> </span></div><p class="subtext">Price</p></div></div><div class=" row PropertyHistoryEventRow" id="propertyHistory-3"><div class="col-4"><p>Sep 5, 2020</p><p class="subtext">Date</p></div><div class="description-col col-4"><div>Listed (Active)</div><div></div><p class="subtext">ACTRIS #5085856</p></div><div class="col-4"><div class="price-col number">$294,900<span class="number empty"> </span></div><p class="subtext">Price</p></div></div></div></div></div>
"""

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

soup.find('div', class_='timeline-content').find('div', class_='price-col number').text
```

**Output**

```
$302,000
```

**Attention**
You have to login to get your provided `html` else it would not contain all the information you like to scrape e.g. `price`

Comment: Thanks! do you have a sample code that can login to redfin from python?